# Creating Navigation Property for Nullable Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm using EntityFramework v4.3.1 and building my model via code by inheriting from DbContext and overriding OnModelCreating(). I have a table called **Companies** and a table called **Messages**. The **Messages** table has a nullable foreign key **Messages.CompanyId**. When this is set, the particular message is associated to a specific company. When this field is null, the message is associated to all companies.

My problem is that I don't know how to express this behaviour in the OnModelCreating() method. If I do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>().HasRequired(o => o.Company).WithMany(o => o.Messages).Map(o => o.MapKey("CompanyId"));
```

I successfully get a navigation property on Company such that I can do calls like TestCompany.Messages and I get a list of messages associated to the particular company. But I also need to have all the null messages returned.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to query messages that are not associated with any company you need to model the scalar property `CompanyId` in the `Message` entity class.

```
public class Message
{
    //other porperties

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

And configure the relationship using `HasOptional` instead of `HasRequired`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
    .HasOptional(o => o.Company).WithMany(o => o.Messages)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId);
```

Then you can query using

```
var messages = db.Messages.Where(m => m.CompanyId == null);
```

Comment: Thanks - I guess I was incorrectly trying to mix model creation with querying. I've seperated those concerns now.

Comment: Is this only possible using the fluent api? Can the `HasOptional` functionality be used from a data annotation?